# Integer number too large error for hexadecimal value

Tags: scala, integer, largenumber

For integers, I can use 'BigInt' if it throws a similar error, what about hexadecimal values? I strictly don't want to convert the hex value into an integer and then use it. Can somebody help?

```
val a = 0x1265465678687564534344536
<console>:1: error: integer number too large
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "For integers, I can use 'BigInt' to solve this issue, what about hexadecimal values" mean? Hexadecimal is a way of representing integers, so what you have there *is* an integer. There is no difference between the integer "Three" written in ternary (`10`), binary (`11`), unary (`111`), decimal (`3`), hexadecimal (`3`), sexagesimal (`3`) or any other base. It is still the same integer.

Comment: "I don't want to convert the hex value into an integer and then use it." – Again, this is unclear. You cannot "convert the hex value into an integer". There is no such thing as a "hex value". Hexadecimal is a way of representing a number in text. It is purely a way of *representing* a value, it is not a value in itself. And the hexadecimal integer literal in your code *already is* an integer value … albeit an illegal one. "I want it strictly to be in hex" – What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

That class [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) has a constructor that takes a **String** argument, so the simple answer is: instead of using a numeric literal, that is out of any meaningful range, create a BigInteger based on "0x1265465678687564534344536" instead!

Answer (score 0):

Use the BigInteger class that takes in a string parameter and pass the radix as 16 to indicate hexadecimal string.

```
new BigInteger(string, 16)
```